# PDF Library require from .NET perspective

Tags: library, pdf, .net

We have to construct/Read PDF form and pre-populate it form reading the database. So looking for excellent PDF library where we can achieve all above mentioned functionality and on top of that it also reduces the form size.

Please let us know from your experience where you have used it.

Regards.

Comment: "PDF libra" do you mean something specific by "libra"? I'm not familiar with that word in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can fill the PDF form by getting the values from the database using **Syncfusion PDF** library. Please refer to the below documentation links for more information,

KB: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9921/how-to-fill-pdf-form-from-database-using-c-and-vb-net

PDF: https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/pdf-library

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms

**Disclosure: I work for Syncfusion**

Regards.

Comment: what is licensing cost?

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm), the library **developed by the company I work for**.

A PDF form is filled like this:

```
PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument("form.pdf");
(document.Form.Fields["firstname"] as PDFTextBoxField).Text = "John";
document.Form.Fields["lastname"].Value = "Doe";
(document.Form.Fields["firstcar"] as PDFDropDownListField).SelectedIndex = 0;
(document.Form.Fields["secondcar"] as PDFListBoxField).SelectedIndex = 1;
(document.Form.Fields["agree"] as PDFCheckBoxField).Checked = true;
// Optionally you can flatten the form
document.Form.FlattenFields();
document.Save("form-filled.pdf");
```

**Disclosure: I work for the company that develops this software.**

Comment: what is licensing cost?

Comment: @ChandrashekharPatidar US$499 per developer with royalty free distribution